# Expanding a variable containing a command doesn't work as expected in a Bash script

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

I have a variable defined as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#commonvars.sh

#Plus other definitions

NUMBERED='nl -w3 -s". " '
```

and then I am using it in another script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source commonvars.sh
$NUMBERED "${DL_FILE}.titles"
```

but the `nl` command doesn't work and gives a usage error.

```
usage: nl [-p] [-b type] [-d delim] [-f type] [-h type] [-i incr] [-l num]
          [-n format] [-s sep] [-v startnum] [-w width] [file]
```

I am sure it must be a tiny little thing, but what exactly am I doing wrong above? The reason I am doing things this way is so that I get a standardized invocation of the `nl` command all over my scripts.

Running on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: Don't put commands in strings. Put them in arrays if you need to do this. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for more details.

Comment: @EtanReisner Could you please add this an answer-of-sorts? I'd like to up-vote it -- this is very useful stuff. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't do that because this sort of question comes up a lot (as indicated by the presence of a FAQ entry for it) and I was looking for a good question to mark this as a duplicate of but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**commonvars.sh:**

**EDITED (I pasted the wrong one before)**

```
NUMBERED=("nl" "-w3" "-s. ")
```

**other script:**

```
source commonvars.sh
"${NUMBERED[@]}"  "${DL_FILE}.titles"
```

You can get a better understanding of whats going on if you set the trace mode before your problematic expansions:

```
set -x
```

Comment: Inside the [x] you specify which element of the array you want. The @ means all the elements.